# "This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 108" error with Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium, chromedriver. I got this error when I started my Test

ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1670846258.729][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 108.

And I also got "Compound class names not permitted" error.

What could be the problem?

chrome version : 108.0.5359.99
Chromedriver version : 108.0.5359.71

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfgCR.png)

I even updated my dependencies to latest version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqgQI.png)

Comment: The error says 'Invalid Selector Exception: Compound class names nor permitted', it is related to the locator you've used, post the code you've tried.

Comment: While you write "Chromedriver version : 108.0.5359.71" the output shows that you are using "Chromedriver version : 107.0.5304.62". But this is just a warning and most probably not the root cause of your problem.